# После сборки в jar перестал работать Dialogs.create()

Tags: javafx, java

В Intellij IDEA 14.0 данный код успешно отрабатывает в проекте, а в .jar-файле - нет.
Среда пишет, что Dialogs Deprecated. Может быть, из-за этого? Он мне нужен > . <.
Других ошибок не наблюдаю, JDK и JRE стоят последние (Java 8 update 25).

```
Action response = Dialogs.create()
        .title("my title")
        .message("some text")
        .actions(Dialog.ACTION_OK)
        .showConfirm();

if (response == Dialog.ACTION_OK) {
    GameApp.currentStage.close();
}
```

**Обновление**

Да, проблема не в Depricated. Проблема в том, что вышеприведенный код я использую из jar-а, который подключен в проект(controlsfx.jar). Структура jar-а почти совпадает со структурой проекта из под IDEA, но код всё равно не работает. При запуске jar-файла ошибка не появляется, потому что нет ассоциированной с ним консоли... А если запустить его из проекта, то выдаст следующую ошибку:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialogs. Ilja

Я только недавно узнал, что можно пилить логи в Run Configuration = )))

Comment: deprecated не влияет на работоспособность. Ищите ошибку в runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил благодаря ресурсу javatalks. Раньше всё никак допереть не мог, как решить эту проблему (да и вообще, КАК её решить?). Наконец-то я понял. Если кому интересно: http://javatalks.ru/topics/20699

Можно было просто положить рядом нужный jar-чик, а в проекте в папке src в Manifest-фаиле прописать Class-Path: yourJarFile.jar

Answer (score 1):

Из приведенного Вами кода, не понятно, в чем дело. На такие случаи нужно, чтобы лог писался в какой-нибудь файл, так и выловите баг. У меня с получаемыми путями до *.jar возникает разница, и программа не работает, как надо, после сборки и запуска из* .jar. Может, и у Вас что-нибудь в этом духе.

Comment: Обновил вопрос